# The best practice to register Azure App configuration in NET.MAUI(public client application)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, maui

I'm curious about the optimal approach for registering Azure App Config in a public client application, specifically in the context of .NET MAUI. My previous experience has mainly been with web apps, where the process was straightforward, as demonstrated below:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
        {
            if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets("21450aac-9897-406f-a964-fe2551a10440");
            }

            var settings = builder.Build();
            var connectionAppConfig = settings["AppConfig"];

            if (!hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                connectionAppConfig = settings.GetConnectionString("AzureAppConfiguration");
            }

            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(connectionAppConfig)
                        .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                        {
                            kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                        }).ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
                        {
                            refreshOptions.Register("ApiApp:IsMaintenance", true);
                            refreshOptions.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                        });
            });
        });
```

In this scenario, connectionAppConfig is sourced from a secret in the development environment and from Azure in the production environment.

Given that my .NET MAUI mobile application isn't hosted on Azure, I'm exploring the best practice for securely storing the application configuration link (connectionAppConfig). While I've come across using SecureStorage, I'm uncertain about the best approach. Even with secure storage, I still need to provide the URL(and I dont want to store it somewhere in code). Any insights on the recommended way to handle this situation?

```
SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync("AppConfig", "Endpoint=https:urltoazureappconfigwithsecret");
var appConfig = SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("AppConfig");
```